# SwiftUI DragGesture swallowed by ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, gesture, draggesture

I want to register a certain drag gesture on any SwiftUI view, including `ScrollViews` simultaneously with any other gestures (i.e. without influencing existing gestures). However, when adding a `DragGesture` on a `ScrollView` as follows, it seems like the gesture is immediately swallowed by the `ScrollView`.

```
ScrollView {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
}
.simultaneousGesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            print("changed:", value.translation)
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            print("ended:", value.translation)
        }
)
```

When I drag the `Rectangle`, this code prints:

```
changed: (3.0, 16.666671752929688)
```

for example.

So `onChanged` is only called once, `onEnded` is never called.

Is there a way to make `DragGestures` work with `ScrollViews` as well?

##### Note:

I tried to find a workaround with `GestureState` and the `updating(_:)` modifier as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: This kind of thing mostly is no possible, and maybe you could find a working code but at the end of the day you are going getting not in 100% working situations there would be always issues. The best  way would be investing on a custom made scroll view, then you have full control.